# Fancybox Image Counter

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, counter

I am using Fancybox Version 1.3.4.  I am trying to include an image counter (Image X of Y) and a "CLOSE X" button at the bottom of my image gallery using Fancybox. I have read several postings that have attempted to solve this, and I have changed my code based on the answers provided, but I still can't seem to correctly code this issue.

Here is the code I have corrected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex,      currentOpts) {
return '<div id="gallery-title">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' +   currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });
```

and

```
<div id="gallery">
<a rel="gallery" href="images/MapDesignImageGallery/full/1.png" title="First Bulgarian            Tsardom (Advanced Cartography/GIS Map of the Year)***PUBLISHED***" id="image1">
<img src="images/MapDesignImageGallery/thumbnails/1.jpg" width="150" height="185" />   </a>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If that is your real code, then you are missing to close the `.ready()` method properly ... you still need `});` at the end of the jQuery code.

Comment: Check http://fancybox.net/blog No. 7 .... not need to read "several" postings

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response! :) Yup, I did close the jQuery code. I have some more code after what I posted but I thought it was extraneous for this post. The Fancybox Tips & Tricks (No. 7) is where I found out what code to write but I guess I am doing something wrong. Any other ideas?